# When I double click a .txt file, I want Windows-7 to open it with my Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio

On my Windows 7 Pro computer, when I double click .txt files, I want Visual Studio 2015 to open them, so I can edit with Visual Studio.

Also, VS does a better job of 'untangling' cr/lf formatting that may be in the .txt file.

Comment: related microsoft tutorial : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click > Open with > Choose default program
Setting default program should get that program to open the desire file extension as a default

Or.. there is a video, and below descriptions for this
[Change which programs Windows uses by default](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7)

• Open Default Programs by clicking the Start button , and then clicking Default Programs.
• Click Associate a file type or protocol with a program.
• Click the file type or protocol that you want the program to act as the default for.
• Click Change program.
• Click the program that you want to use as the default for the file type you selected, or click the arrow next to Other Programs to show additional programs. (If you don't see Other Programs, or your program is not listed, click Browse to find the program you want to use, and then click Open. If no other programs are installed that are able to open the file type or protocol, your choices will be limited.)
note: If you don't see the program you want to use as the default, click the arrow next to Other Programs to see a list of programs available on your computer 
• Click OK.

Comment: right-click no longer shows "Open with" on my Windows-7 Pro.   So I do: Windows Explorer > Open menu > Choose default program

Answer (score 0):

If 'Open With' doesn't show then rightClick --> properties--> General click on Change button, select the default program with which it has to be opened.